# Dispaly range of values from ID table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want display the date range for my ID like from ID 4 to 6 (means not using limit) but as shown in the picture [All value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2yrt.png)
In my code all the values store in category table is displaying I just want to display only first three records.

my code is here

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM category order by id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo '
  <span id="rcorners2"><a href="home.php?page=category&category='.$row["category"].'">'.$row["category"].'</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: You appear to be modifying your code incrementally from previously asked questions.

Comment: Yes because I am trying to resolve the errors. I have tried BETWEEN function and WHERE but not works.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use limit  3

```
SELECT * FROM category order by id ASC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: What if I want a range from 4 to 6